# US Tourist Visa - If I move, do I have to pay the fees again?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

> Some locals state that they got their tourist visas in last few months.
>
> Some locals state that current appointments are given for 2023 at the soonest.
>
> Some locals state that they were able to change their appointments
> dates to a much sooner date online by constantly checking if there are
> new available spots.
>
> https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html
> states "Emergency Appointments Only".

MRV fee is $160. I think I need to pay that so I can schedule an appointment.

But before my appointment, I might move to another country. In that case, do I need to pay another $160?

I don't know when or if I'd move. So I'd like to apply now.

Comment: Ate you asking about moving before or after the visa is issued?

Comment: @phoog What do you mean by Ate?

Comment: @user124301 'Are'

Comment: Yes, Mark Johnson is correct: my phone second-guessed me.  It should be "are you asking..."

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Where are you planning to apply from/where might you move to? This https://japan2.usembassy.gov/pdfs/wwwf-visa-reschedule-e.pdf for example states *You may change or cancel your interview appointment up to two times. If you use your receipt for the 3rd time to schedule, the following warning message appears on the screen to inform you that this is your last time to schedule with the current receipt number. “If you cancel this appointment, then you will have exceeded the limit of appointments canceled, and will not be able to schedule another appointment until another MRV fee has been paid”